# Examining convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ with mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to examine convergence of the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$$

My approach is the following:
$$\frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\ln(\frac{n+1}{n})}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\sqrt{n}}\le \frac{\ln(2)}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Because the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(2)}{\sqrt{n}}$ is absolutely convergent, our series is also absolutely covergent.

It was my solution. Can  you show me how to prove convergence using the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)?

Comment: Are you sure that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(2)}{\sqrt{n}}$  is absolutely convergent ?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}‌​\frac{\ln(2)}{\sqrt{n‌​}}=\ln(2)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}‌​\frac{1}{\sqrt{n‌​}}$  Yes, it is absolutely covergent.

Comment: I'm sorry, my head is such exhausted in last days...... You are right, of course..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the Mean Value theorem, there exists $c_n \in (n,n+1)$ such that
$$
\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)=\frac1{c_n} <\frac1n
$$ giving, for $n=1,2,\cdots$,
$$
0<\frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}} <\frac1{n\sqrt{n}}
$$
and$$
0<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{3/2}}<\infty.
$$ The latter series being a convergent $p$-series.