# Showing convergence or divergance of the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(k+1)-\ln(k)}{\sqrt{k+1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm stuck on this problem where I would like to show the convergance or divergance of the following series.

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(k+1)-\ln(k)}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$

My original approach was using the comparison test with the following expression:
$$\frac{\ln(\frac{k+1}{k})}{\sqrt{k+1}}\le \frac{\ln(2)}{\sqrt{k}}$$

However, I believe this approach is wrong since it gives a divergent series. I also looked into using the Mean Value Theorem, as discussed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1894903/1198061), however I don't fully understand the reasoning behind it or if I can apply it to this very similar problem. Sorry if this question is to similiar to the one linked, I was unsure if it was better to bump the other question or ask a completely new one!

Comment: Hint: for $x\in (0,1),$ $\ln(1+x)<x$.

Comment: Now that this post has 4 nice answers, probably we should close the old one as a duplicate of this one instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also find the leading order term,
$$\frac{\log(k+1)-\log(k)}{\sqrt{k+1}}=\frac{\log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{k}\right)}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$
by Taylor's formula and the Binomial expansion,
$$\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)=\frac{1}{k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\\
\sqrt{k+1}=\sqrt k+O\left(\frac{1}{k^{1/2}}\right)$$
as $k\to+\infty$, hence,
$$\frac{\log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{k}\right)}{\sqrt{k+1}}=\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^{5/2}}\right)$$
as $k\to+\infty$. The series is convergent.

Comment: When using this method, are you using the series expansion at $k=\infty$ or $k=0$ for $\sqrt{k+1}$? If I'm not mistaken, the first is the Taylor series for the expansion and the other is the Puiseux series?

Comment: @Garlic6522. As we are taking the limit as $k\to\infty$, we use expansions as $k\to\infty$. I believe the second is a Puiseux series as it involves fractional exponents, but to derive it you first encounter the Laurent series through the Binomial expansion,
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{1/2}=1+\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{8k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$
then multiply by $\sqrt k$ and the Puiseux series will follow.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the mean value theorem, yes.

By it, we know $\exists \xi_n \in [n,n+1]$ such that
$$
\frac{\ln(n+1) - \ln(n)}{(n+1)-n}
= \ln(n+1) - \ln(n)
= \frac{d}{dx} \ln(x) \bigg|_{x=\xi_n}
= \frac{1}{\xi_n}
$$
and, since $\xi_n \in [n,n+1]$, we know
$$
\frac{1}{\xi_n} \le \frac{1}{n}
$$
Then
$$
\frac{\ln(n+1) - \ln(n)}{\sqrt{n+1}}
< \frac{1}{n \sqrt{n+1}}
< \frac{1}{n \sqrt n} = \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}
$$
which follows as $\sqrt n < \sqrt{n+1}$ (which is the key step to applying the result of the linked problem to your own).

Answer (score 2):

For all $k\geq 1$, from the graph of $y=\frac1x,$

$$\frac{\ln(k+1)-\ln k}{\sqrt{k+1}}=\frac{\int_k^{k+1}\frac1xdx}{\sqrt{k+1}}<\frac{\frac1k}{\sqrt k}=\frac{1}{k^{3/2}}.$$

Hence, by comparison test and $p$-test,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(k+1)-\ln k}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$ converges.

Answer (score 2):

This answer doesn't make use of calculus. It is based solely on the Euler construction of the number $e.$

Since $${(k+1)^k\over k^k}=\left (1+{1\over k}\right)^k<e$$ by applying $\log$ we get $$k[\log (k+1)-\log k]<1$$ Hence $$0<{\log(k+1)-\log k\over \sqrt{k+1}}< {1\over k\sqrt{k}}\\ 
<{2\over \sqrt{k-1}\sqrt{k}[\sqrt{k-1}+\sqrt{k}]}
\\ ={2}\left ({1\over \sqrt{k-1}}-{1\over \sqrt{k}}\right ) $$ Thus the series is convergent.

Comment: But how can we show that $(1+\frac1k)^k<e$?

Comment: @BobDobbs The original definition of $e$ is the limit of $(1+1/k)^k.$ In order to prove the limit exists we  show that the sequence $(1+1/k)^k.$ is increasing while the sequence $(1+1/k)^{k+1}$ is decreasing. Look up any textbook where $e$ is defined.